# understanding assembly return to main

Tags: assembly, att

I have the following code :

```
0x401050    <main>:         push   %ebp
0x401051    <main+1>:       mov    %esp,%ebp
0x401053    <main+3>:       sub    $0x8,%esp
0x401056    <main+6>:       and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x401059    <main+9>:       mov    $0x0,%eax
0x40105e    <main+14>:      mov    %eax,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x401061    <main+17>:      mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
0x401064    <main+20>:      call   0x4013a0 <_alloca>
0x401069    <main+25>:      call   0x401430 <__main>
0x40106e    <main+30>:      mov    $0x0,%edx
0x401073    <main+35>:      add    0x8(%ebp),%edx
0x401076    <main+38>:      mov    %edx,%eax
0x401078    <main+40>:      leave  
0x401079    <main+41>:      ret
```

I'm trying to understand what value returns from main(register `eax`).
I don't really understand what is the purpose of storing `0` in `0xfffffffc(%ebp)` and then back to `eax` :

```
0x40105e    <main+14>:      mov    %eax,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x401061    <main+17>:      mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
```

and what is going to be in `0x8(%ebp)`, so what is going to be after adding it to `eax`

```
0x401073    <main+35>:      add    0x8(%ebp),%edx
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, we should ask *you* why you have all these superfluous operations in *your* code. And if this is not your code, they you have to explain how you obtained it. Is this code compiled from C code? If so, then what was the original C code and what were the compiler optimization settings?

Comment: This code was given to me in a quiz, I don't know anything besides that the code is compiled from C

Comment: The question as asked is not related to C. And this is not a decompilation or "explain the code" service.

Comment: @Olaf I did not ask for a "service" all I did is asked for help in something that I don't understand. I spent some time trying to understand it before I posted my question here. If it is considered to do a "service" for me by answering the question then you're welcome to delete the post, I'll ask for help somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: compile with `-Og` for less braindead compiler output that still does pretty much what the source says.  (optimize-for-debugging).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has clearly been compiled with optimizations off, which is why you see strange things. The return value is going to be the first argument of `main` which is `argc`.
The original C code might have looked like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    size_t size = 0;        // local variable at -4(%ebp) = 0xfffffffc(%ebp)
    _alloca(size);
    __main();
    return 0 + argc;        // argc at 8(%ebp)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, messed up the return value.

Comment: I'm just getting off dealing with the flu, but how does `-4(%ebp)` translate to the first parameter of `_alloca` since `sub    $0x8,%esp` set the stack pointer 8 below where _EBP_ was. Given that this is clearly code targeting Windows, I'm wondering what the calling convention is here (on Windows there are a variety available). So despite the fact I think your answer is a good one, i'm still a bit stumped as how the actual code shown works.

Comment: The code likely works. My guess is that the prologue goes all the way up to just after calling `__main`. `__main` generally has to be called in `_main` when using the C++ runtime on Windows. `__main` among other things does CTOR initialization etc. I could have almost believed the code that generated this was `int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0 + argc;
}` Only issue there I guess is that the code is so badly optimized it almost look like someone hacked it together manually.

Comment: @MichaelPetch `_alloca` uses a special convention with `eax` for input argument.

Comment: @Jester, I concur that it is the convention for `_alloca` in this environment. I primarily brought up the issue to just make it clear to any person coming by this question and answer that there is a bit more going on here. I was one of your upvoters already.